# Xamarin - CollectionView VerticalItemSpacing not working

Tags: xamarin, spacing, collectionview

I am clueless what might be wrong, I've tested several code variants and none of them worked. I've also tried variant with Frame and StackLayout.

```
<ScrollView VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <CollectionView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="StockCards_CollectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding lc_ReleaseBill.Items}" SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged}" EmptyView="List is empty." SelectionMode="Single"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStockCard, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"  VerticalItemSpacing="20"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Start" TextColor="White"/>

                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Unit}" FontAttributes="Italic"  VerticalOptions="Start" TextColor="White"/>

                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding Price_WithVAT_Unit}" FontAttributes="Bold"  HorizontalOptions="End" FontSize="19" TextColor="#00c8df"/>

                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding Amount}" FontAttributes="Bold"  HorizontalOptions="End" TextColor="White"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </Grid>
</ScrollView>
```

Running on Xamarin.Forms 4.5.0.356 and the same result was on 4.4.0.991640.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed it by setting Collection View Item Spacing from code, which is not ideal but its better than setting margin on Grid inside of Collection View.

```
CollectionView.ItemsLayout = new LinearItemsLayout(ItemsLayoutOrientation.Vertical)
    {
       ItemSpacing = 20
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try adding Margin to the DataTemplate Content inside a ContentView

```
<CollectionView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="StockCards_CollectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding lc_ReleaseBill.Items}" SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged}" EmptyView="List is empty." SelectionMode="Single"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStockCard, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentView>
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,20">
                   ...
                </Grid>
            <(ContentView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Also, you should try using `ItemSpacing="20"` instead of `VerticalItemSpacing`

Edit: Since the ItemSpacing does work, but only after it has some more items in it enough for the scroll back and foward, i would try this technique:

Set the `IsVisible` property to false, and after your Collection has data, set it to true:

```
<CollectionView IsVisible="{Binding CollectionHasData}" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="StockCards_CollectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding lc_ReleaseBill.Items}" SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged}" EmptyView="List is empty." SelectionMode="Single"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStockCard, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

---

```
private bool _collectionHasData;

public bool CollectionHasData
{
    get => _item;
    set { _collectionHasData = value; }
}

...

lc_ReleaseBill.Items = Data;
CollectionHasData = true;
```

I don't know how you fetch your data, if you set it or the object already has the data, but the point is, when your Items has some values, set the bool to true

Comment: Thanks Ricardo.

<Grid Margin="0,0,0,20">
               ...
            </Grid>

This is working of course but with one downside, when you select item, the whole area including margin is highlighted.

I've also tried ItemSpacing variant, but without result.

<CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
     <LinearItemsLayout  Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="20"/>
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

Comment: @Kalixt i'm glad i could help! don't forget to market it as the correct anwser, also i just made an edit to fix the issue you said, try put your grid inside a <ContentView></ContentView> and see if it works

Comment: @Kalixt your you could even try using Padding instead of Margin

Comment: Ricardo, Padding have the same downside as Margin. I dont want to replace CollectionView item spacing by setting up padding or margin on grid. CollectionView item spacing should work, but I noticed that when I fill collection with few items and go back one page and back to collection view, item spacing is working, which means I need to reload collection view somehow when new items are added.

Comment: @Kalixt so the item spacing does work, you might want to try this technique: start the CollectionView IsVisible to false, and when you have item's in your collection, set it to true, i will update once again my Answer

Comment: Turning on visibility after items were added didn't work. Item spacing doesn't work until I reload page or control, but it would be better solution for sure, because I am breaking MVVM model.

Comment: @Kalixt Yes.. i think you should open a ticket or create a issue on the Github, because that's not an normal behaviour, i thought it wasn't updating the properties, and usually visibility changes trigger that

Answer (score 0):

Margin and spacing have do not get updated for a new item added, the only way they get updated is if they are scrolled off then back on the screen.